# upload pdf and image files using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

my mobile app uploads pdf files and images files to server.
I could upload image files using below code.

API definition

```java
@Multipart
@POST("/api/images/upload")
Call<ImageUploadResponse> uploadImage(@Header("x-auth-token") String authHeader, @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> image);
```

on select of any image file from storage

```java
if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE){
 if (data.getClipData() != null) {
   List<byte[]> imageDataList = new ArrayList<>();
   int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     try {
        bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),imageUri);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos);
        imageDataList.add(baos.toByteArray());
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
    uploadImage(imageDataList);
 }
```

build multi part body part request.

```
private void uploadImage( List<byte[]> imageDataList) {
              
     MultipartBody.Part[]  parts =  new MultipartBody.Part[imageDataList.size()];
     for (int i = 0; i < imageDataList.size(); i++) {
          RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), imageDataList.get(i));
          String fileName = "image" + i + ".jpg";
          MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", fileName, requestFile);
          parts[i] = body;
  }
 String token = sessionCache.getToken();
 Call<ImageUploadResponse> call = apiInterface.uploadImage(token,parts);
        
 call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageUploadResponse>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<ImageUploadResponse> call, Response<ImageUploadResponse> response) {
            List<String> pdfPaths = response.body().getPdf();
            List<String> imagePaths = response.body().getImg();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "image scanned/attached",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        
     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<ImageUploadResponse> call, Throwablet) {
        
      }
       });
}
```

How could I upload a pdf file?
I am struggling to get the absolute path of pdf file from URI

Comment: First upload your image files using the obtained uri and without using an intermediate bitmap. When you are ready you can use the same code to upload a pdf file. Or any other file.

Comment: And you do not need a path to upload a file if you have a nice uri.

Comment: bmp=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),imageUri);  return null for pdf file. I works for image file

Comment: Yes of course it returns null for a pdf. A pdf file is no image file. You did not read my comments it seems.

Comment: Yes. I misinterpreted ur comment. can you please point me code to do "upload your image files using the obtained uri and without using an intermediate bitmap". I am uploading a file local to my mobile - ex of uri : content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A21602

Comment: Well you can handle files in byte arrays: ` imageDataList.add(baos.toByteArray());` So put the bytes of you pdf file in a byte array and then add that byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openInputStream(uri) to get the InputStream and convert the InputStream to byte array solved the problem for image and pdf. get the mime type from clipData and use the same mime type while constructing RequestBody.

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  ..............
  ..............
  if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
        List<byte[]> imageDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); 
        String mimeType = data.getClipData().getDescription().getMimeType(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
           imageDataList.add(getBytes(imageUri));
        }
       // pass the byte array list to be uploaded.
       handleAttachment(imageDataList, mimeType);
     }
}


private byte[] getBytes(Uri uri) {
   try {
      InputStream inputStream = getActivity()
                   .getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            return readBytes(inputStream);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.d("could not get byte stream",ex)
        }
        return null;
    }

  private byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // and then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }

    private void handleAttachment(List<byte[]> imageDataList, String mimeType) {

        List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < imageDataList.size(); i++) {
            MultipartBody.Part body = null;
            switch (mimeType) {
                case MimeTypeConst.imageMimeTypeInRequest:
                    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MimeTypeConst.imageMimeType),
                            imageDataList.get(i));
                    String fileName = "attachment" + i + ".jpg";
                    body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", fileName, requestFile);
                    break;
                case MimeTypeConst.pdfMimeType:
                     requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MimeTypeConst.pdfMimeType),
                            imageDataList.get(i));
                    fileName = "attachment" + i + ".pdf";
                    body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", fileName, requestFile);
                    break;
            }
            parts.add(body);
        }
        uploadAttachment(parts);
    }
```